Crase antes de palavras estrangeiras?
Existe alguma regra específica sobre crase precedendo de palavras estrangeiras (especialmente inglês)? Já consultei algumas gramáticas aqui e não encontrei uma regra específica.
Em tese, poderia haver crase em função do gênero da tradução. Isso porque, como as palavras de algumas línguas estrangeiras não tem gênero ou é diverso do gênero em português, o artigo mais correto seria o que concordasse com a tradução (ex. a call – a chamada), mas frequentemente isso não acontece (ex. a thread – o fio).
Se não existe regra, qual o mais usual?

"a" em inglês não significa nem 'a' nem 'o', significa um ou uma. Não entendo da qual "concordância" estás a falar em termos do "a" inglês.

De qualquer maneira...o crase aparece somente quando "a" precede certas palavras. Não vejo isto acontecendo aqui?

Você precisa dar um exemplo. O inglês não tem nada que ver. Depende do português. A questão é: tem um verbo seguido da preposição a + um substantivo no feminino no texto em português? E não tem nada a ver com tradução.

A origem da palavra não tem influência sobre o uso da crase.
Se a palavra estrangeira é usada no português, não tem escapatória: um gênero tem que ser atribuído a ela (a fashion week, o delivery). E as regras gramaticais se aplicam sem alterações, e.g., "Nunca fui à fashion week."

Não entendo. Ir + a, mas fashion week é feminino?? Acho que ficaria sem crase.

@Lambie Você acha que seria "o fashion week"? Até encontrei um exemplo masculino em Angola, aqui, mas o feminino me parece mais natural e é o que encontrei aqui e aqui. E ou se escreve "ir à week" ou "ao week", assim como se escreveria "ir ao show" e "ir à academia".

Eu acho melhor sem nada. o verbo ir leva a, então ficaria: fui ou assisti a Fashion Week, sem nada mais, né? Como no caso de: fui a Paris.

O gênero de Paris é relativo, vários latins têm a mesma discussão sobre https://www.elcastellano.org/pablo-23 https://www.projet-voltaire.fr/culture-generale/genre-noms-villes-masculin-feminin/. Por Fashion Week ser nome próprio, pode ser que se omita o artigo, mas nunca ouvi ninguém omitindo, sempre ouvi "A Fashion Week".

Verdade, também há a opção sem artigo. Mas como é um evento ou período, acho estranho sem artigo, "fui ao réveillon, ao Rock in Rio, à Saturnália, ao carnaval..."

Sim parece ser mais feminino do que masculino. E olha só o que encontrei: Favela Fashion Week https://www.ouvirmusica.com.br/leandro-sapucahy/1894673/ De certo modo é muito machista, sexista etc. De outro, é a cultura popular. Credo. :) Fiquei um pouco pasmada.
